# Preprocessor loop over sequence of header files

Tags: c++, boost-preprocessor

Is it possible to include a sequence of files: `file1,file2,file3` 
in a preprocessor loop?

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/iteration/local.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/cat.hpp>

// needed whitespace here----*
#define BOOST_PP_LOCAL_LIMITS (1, 3)

#define GENERATE_FILE_NAME(n) \
   BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE( BOOST_PP_CAT( file , n) ) \
   /**/

#define BOOST_PP_LOCAL_MACRO(n) \
    #include GENERATE_FILE_NAME(n) \
```

and then using it with:

```
#include BOOST_PP_LOCAL_ITERATE()
```

should expand to

```
BOOST_PP_LOCAL_MACRO(1) --> includes file1
BOOST_PP_LOCAL_MACRO(2) --> includes file2
BOOST_PP_LOCAL_MACRO(3) --> includes file3
```

Unfortunately the above does not work because of the  `#include GENERATE_FILE_NAME(n)` in a macro which does not expand...

Is this even possible?

**Comment:**
I posted this question because I was wondering if this is even possible. I have solved my problem by including just one file which was generated from all files `file1 file2 file3`. I came across this, because sometimes one might generate big include file sequences (which should not be merged, just because of readability) and I was unsure how to include all those without writing explicitly all file names, so I thought about preprocessor loops, which is of course uglier then my solution so far :-), but its fancier :-)

Comment: Depending on situation, it might be better to automatically generate a header file which includes all these headers, and then only include this auto-generated header file.

Comment: I could think of several uses if you could also concatenate the loop index into defines

Comment: I think this would be difficult since the C and C++ standards have this wording in their clauses about rescanning during macro replacement, " The resulting completely macro-replaced preprocessing token sequence is not processed as a preprocessing directive even if it resembles one". However, I've seen some very surprising techniques used with the preprocessor, so I'm not bold enough to say it can't be done.

Comment: I use this to construct some code in a BOOST_PP_LOCAL_MACRO (which is more complex as the one above) loop which then includes one file after another

Comment: Regarding Jonathans question, you might want to read [about the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You only present us with a solution you want to use, but you don't tell us what problem you try to solve. There may be other, or even better, solutions.

Comment: Is it necessary to do this with a preprocessor or would it be better to have a pre build script that runs?

Comment: C++ and C have `#define` macros of different capability. Are you looking for a C solution or a C++ solution? For the moment I will remove the C tag.

Comment: Ok, I posted this question because I was wondering if this is even possible. I have solved my problem by including just one file which was generated from all files ``file1 file2 file3``.
I came across this, because sometimes one would like to generate big include files sequences (which should not be merged, just because of readability) and I was unsure how to include all those without writing explicitly all file names, so I thought about preprocessor loops, which is of course uglier then my solution so far :-), but its fancier :-)

Answer (score 1):

This works with g++:

Having a directory preprocessor in the include path and this include_range.h:

```
#if !BOOST_PP_IS_ITERATING

#ifndef INCLUDE_RANGE_PREFIX
    #error Missing INCLUDE_RANGE_PREFIX
#endif
#ifndef INCLUDE_RANGE_MIN
    #error Missing INCLUDE_RANGE_MIN
#endif
#ifndef INCLUDE_RANGE_MAX
    #error Missing INCLUDE_RANGE_MAX
#endif

#include <boost/preprocessor/iteration/iterate.hpp>

#define BOOST_PP_ITERATION_PARAMS_1 (3, \
    (INCLUDE_RANGE_MIN, INCLUDE_RANGE_MAX, <preprocessor/include_range.h>))
#include BOOST_PP_ITERATE()

#else

#define INCLUDE_RANGE_PATH_SUFFIX(F, N) F##N
#define INCLUDE_RANGE_PATH(F, N) <INCLUDE_RANGE_PATH_SUFFIX(F, N)>
#include INCLUDE_RANGE_PATH(INCLUDE_RANGE_PREFIX, BOOST_PP_ITERATION())

#if BOOST_PP_ITERATION_DEPTH() == INCLUDE_RANGE_MAX - INCLUDE_RANGE_MIN + 1
    #undef INCLUDE_RANGE_PREFIX
    #undef INCLUDE_RANGE_MIN
    #undef INCLUDE_RANGE_MAX
#endif

#endif
```

You can include a range of files (file2, file3, file4):

```
#define INCLUDE_RANGE_PREFIX file
#define INCLUDE_RANGE_MIN 2
#define INCLUDE_RANGE_MAX 4
#include <preprocessor/include_range.h>
```

Limitation: The files are in the include path.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the things which are happening here,
I see some recursive ``#include INCLUDE_RANGE_PATH(INCLUDE_RANGE_PREFIX, BOOST_PP_ITERATION())``

Comment: @Gabriel That #include INCLUDE_RANGE_PATH ... is not recursive, it is just an evaluation of the result of #include BOOST_PP_ITERATE()